# How to filter rows according to specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume that we have a table such as below:

**Table A:**

```
  x  |  y  

  V1 |  5  
  V2 |  2  
  V3 |  0  
  V4 |  3
```

How can filter this table rows such that show the rows above 0 in y field. That is I want to pretermit V3 and V4 rows and show the others.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there are no rows "above" another row.  Ordering can be introduced with another column.

Let me assume that `x` is ordered.  Then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.x < (select min(t2.x) from t t2 where t2.y = 0);
```

Comment: To expand on this, the part of the query in brackets is just getting the X value for the row where Y=0. The 'min' function is used to ensure it only returns a single value, in case there were multiple rows where Y=0.